# Missing steps in my Github Actions workflow for deploying a Flutter and Node.js app to Digital Ocean

Tags: node.js, flutter, devops

I am working on a github action workflow file that deploys my web app built on flutter (front-end) and node backend to my digital ocean server. But there seems to be missing parts of the whole process that i don't understand. Here is how i am modelling the whole process:

- check out your github code
- specify the vm that your workflow file runs on.
- install node in the vm
- install flutter in the vm
- install npm dependencies in the backend folder
- build your production node app
- get flutter dependencies in the respective folders of my flutter apps
- build flutter web apps in their respective folder
- get into digital ocean
- copy my built apps into their respective folders

As i am not familliar with devops, i might be missing something in my model. I am also familiar with building docker images and i know it might be useful in this case, but i don't how to put the different parts together.

Here is my yaml file for githu actions :

name: niti staging deployment

on:
push:
tags:
- stage-*

jobs:
build-and-deploy:
runs-on: ubuntu-latest
steps:
- name: Checkout Repository
uses: actions/checkout@v2

```
  - name: Set up node.js
    uses: actions/setup-node@v2-beta
    with:
      node-version: '14.x'

  - name: install node dependencies
    working-directory: ./backend
    run: npm install

  - name: build backend
    working-directory: ./backend
    run: npm run build

  - name: set up flutter
    uses: subosito/flutter-actions@v1
    with:
      flutter-version: '3.10.0'

  - name: get flutter dependencies for admin
    working-directory: ./frontend/admin
    run: flutter pub get

  - name: build admin app
    working-directory: ./frontend/admin
    run: flutter build web

  - name: get flutter dependencies for customer
    working-directory: ./frontend/customer
    run: flutter pub get

  - name: build customer app
    working-directory: ./frontend/customer
    run: flutter build web

  - name: build vendor app
    working-directory: ./frontend/vendor
    run: flutter build web

  //figure out how to transfer build to digital ocean
```

I'd appreciate help in understanding how the whole system works. Thank you